# Error trying to diff 'object Object'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed NgFor

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have a JSON file, with a list of for sale properties. I am trying to use *NgFor to loop through the data to create a list.

Firstly I am still an amateur with angular and app development so there is a possibility I may have misinterpreted documentation etc

I have tried looping through different paths

```
*NgFor="let post of posts.properties"
*NgFor="let post of posts.properties.property"
```

and still getting various errors.

My understanding, is I have to cast the observable to an array of properties. And then bind it to the html. (Which I believe I have done as properties is of type array?

json

```
{
    "properties": {
        "property": [
            {
                "propertyID": "101552000007",
                "branchID": "1",
                "clientName": "A Demo",
                "branchName": "Brackley",
                "department": "Sales",
                "referenceNumber": "10006",
                "addressName": "",
                "addressNumber": "87",
                "addressStreet": "Hackney Road",
```

properties.interface.ts

```
export interface IProperties {
    addressStreet: string;
    addressNumber: number;
}
```

For-sale.service.ts

```
import { IProperties } from './../properties.interface';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ForSaleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }


  getProperties(): Observable<IProperties[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProperties[]>('/assets/data/jupix.json');

  }

}
```

for-sale.page.ts

```
import { ForSaleService } from './for-sale.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-for-sale',
  templateUrl: './for-sale.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./for-sale.page.scss'],
  providers: [ForSaleService]
})
export class ForSalePage implements OnInit {

  public properties = [];

  constructor(private saleService: ForSaleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.onGetProperties();

  }



  onGetProperties() {
    this.saleService.getProperties()
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.properties = response;
      });
  }
}
```

html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let property of properties">
    <ion-card>

      <ion-card-header>{{ property.addressNumber }}</ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>
          <ion-icon name="person" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What I don't understand is, let property of properties is bound to the array of properties?

EDIT: After trying a few suggestions, there appears to be a pattern emerging to the errors in the console log? It appears to see child elements as undefined as these are the ones throwing errors?

So i changed the variable completely to propertiesList to make it easier to read.
A really weird thing is occuring now.
So we have `*ngFor="let property of propertiesList.properties.property"`

Then for the card image `<img src="{{ property.images.image[0].__text }}" alt="">`
 
This works as intended, the image shows. However in the console log `Cannot read property '__text' of undefined` and the original `" Cannot read property 'property' of undefined`

So i continued adding other elements in the html

`<ion-card-header>{{ property.addressNumber }} {{ property.addressStreet }} {{ property.addressPostcode }}</ion-card-header>`

These work fine, no errors, data displays. Now this is where it gets weird.

`<p>{{ property.propertyFeature1 }} {{ property.floorplans.floorplan._modified }}</p>`

I now add this, and `Cannot read property '__text' of undefined` vanishes! and is instead replaced with `Cannot read property '__modified' of undefined` along with the original `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined`

In visual studio code, the only error im getting is `Identifier 'properties' is not defined. 'Array' does not contain such a member`

Comment: Please Check this `*ngIf="properties.properties.property?.length > 0"` before the loop

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables):

> An `object` is iterable if it defines its iteration behavior, such as what values are looped over in a for...of construct. Some built-in types, such as `Array` or `Map`, have a default iteration behavior, while other types (such as `Object`) do not.

Change the ngFor to the following:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let property of properties.property">
```

Then you will be able to iterate since it is an array.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response. I tried that and get an error
"property properties of ForSalePage
Identifier 'property' is not defined. 'Array' does not contain such a memberAngular"

Comment: what does `response` give you?

Comment: if `console.log(response)` gives you the json that you shared then do `let property of properties.properties.property"`

Comment: Ahh success!

`console.log(response)` does respond with the json.

Using `*ngFor="let property of properties.properties.property"`

`<ion-card-header>{{ property.addressNumber }} {{ property.addressStreet }}</ion-card-header>`

This is working, and is showing expected results, however there is still an error
" Cannot read property 'property' of undefined"

Comment: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined" Is in the console log (multiple times)

And in visual studio code, the error "Identifier 'properties' is not defined. 'Array' does not contain such a member" in the NgFor

Comment: okay change your variable `this.properties` to `this.responses` and change the ngfor to this `<ion-list *ngFor="let ds of responses.properties.property"> <ion-card-header>{{ ds .addressNumber }}</ion-card-header>` please mark the answer as correct if it helped you, by clicking on the check mark next to it  thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't `this.respopnse` be the same as `this.properties`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I have added an edit to my op as some more testing revealed some strange things

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Check `*ngIf="properties.properties.property?.length > 0"` condition before the loop so it will check whether array or object is empty or not.

```
 <ion-content *ngIf="properties.properties.property?.length > 0">
      <ion-list *ngFor="let property of properties.properties.property">
       <ion-card>

        <ion-card-header>{{ property.addressNumber }}</ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <p>
           <ion-icon name="person" color="primary"></ion-icon>
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
   </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

so you will not get any error in console like  `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined`

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the get call cannot correctly map your data to your properties defined in your Interface.  As the mapping is not correct is won't be a correct array that can be looped over.

based on what you provided with all the variables, you need to loop over it via:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let property of properties.properties.property">
```

properties as your result array, then properties as a property of the json + property as an actually array with data...
don't even know if this two identical identifiers are going to work

Comment: Hi, some suggested this, and this is working as inteded? I say intended? As now using string interpolation, the data is looping but in the console log i am receiving the error `" Cannot read property 'property' of undefined` and in visual studio code `Identifier 'properties' is not defined. 'Array' does not contain such a member`

This is the first time i have done this, but i can't help but feel like the interface array isn't working as intended?